# Flex/Actionscript determine if NetStream has audio by analysing audioBytesPerSecond

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, audio, actionscript, flex3

I need to "look" at a NetStream and determine if I'm receiving audio. From what I investigated, i may use the property audioBytesPerSecond from NetStreamInfo:

> "(audioBytesPerSecond) Specifies the rate at which the NetStream audio
>   buffer is filled in bytes per second. The value is calculated as a
>   smooth average for the audio data received in the last second."

I also learned that NetStream may have contain some overhead bytes from the network so, which is the minimum reasonable audioBytesPerSecond value to determine if NetStream is playing audio (and not just noise, for example)?
Can this analysis be done this way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it this way. It's rather subjective, however.

Try to find a threshold that works for you. We used 5 kilobits/sec in the past. If the amount of data falls below this value, they are likely not sending any audio. Note, we were using the `stream.info.byteCount` property (you might want a slightly lower value if you're using `auiodBytesPerSecond`).

This is pretty easy to observe if you speak into the microphone and periodically check `audioBytesPerSecond` or the other counters/statistics that are available.

Comment: Hi Sunil, thanks for replying. Just a question, in your case, when using byteCount, which minimum value did you tested? Using bytesPerSecond here seems ok when tested against 5KB anyway :)

Comment: We used 5 kilobits/second. So we converted the byteCount to bits.

Comment: PS: if you use byte count, its a running total of bytes sent  so you have to do extra work to calculate the rate. AudioBytesPerSecond does all that work for you :)